# How can the pixie dust effect be brought about using skrollr plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, skrollr

Recently I viewed the ScrollMagic Demo website.
It showed the pixie dust sparkling effect been brought across on movement of the wand.

How can the effect be brought about using skrollr plugin?

Please guide me on that one.

[Here](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) is the reference link

Answer (score 0):

Go for an animated .gif with alpha channel showing sparks and trigger its opacity from 0 to 1 when in position with skrollr... but also trigger the animation.

.Gifs can be configured natively (photoshop) to play once to infinite but guess you'll need to find a way to trigger the gif animation once it's at "X" opacity.